# Dart - How to force map key to be contained in a list strings

Tags: typescript, dart

Let's say I have the following map that has `key1` and `key2`:

```
Map<String, bool> _map = {
  'dog': true,
  'cat': true
};
```

Now, I want to enforce Dart to allow only a certain of keys. In Typescript, I could do something like:

```
enum AvailableKeysEnum {
  Dog = 'dog',
  Cat = 'cat'
}

interface AvailableKeys {
  [key in AvailableKeysEnum]: boolean;
}

const availableKeys: AvailableKeys = {
  'dog': true, // Allowed
  'cat': true, // Allowed
  'dolphin': true // Denied
}
```

My question is, how can I enforce Dart to allow only a certain keys?

Comment: There isn't really a way to do that in Dart (yet) except perhaps creating a custom Map implementation, which is not too hard (using https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-collection/MapMixin-class.html) but probably still not worth it.

Comment: Dart and Typescript are very different languages. Typescript has structural type system. This allows such features in Typescript. A structural type system (or property-based type system) is a major class of type system, in which type compatibility and equivalence are determined by the type's actual structure or definition, and not by other characteristics such as its name or place of declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood it correctly (I don't know TypeScript)

Dart doesn't have key constraints so will have to extend the Map and implement those constraints. Here is code for that.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class InvalidKeyError<K> extends Error {
  final Object key;
  final Set<K> keys;

  InvalidKeyError(this.key, this.keys);

  @override
  String toString() => "InvalidKeyError: $key not found in $keys";
}

class SpecialMap<K, V> extends MapMixin<K, V> {
  final Set<K> availableKeys;

  final Map<K, V> _map = {};

  SpecialMap(this.availableKeys) : assert(availableKeys != null);

  @override
  Iterable<K> get keys => _map.keys;

  @override
  void clear() => _map.clear();

  @override
  V remove(Object key) => _map.remove(key);

  @override
  V operator [](Object key) => availableKeys.contains(key)
      ? _map[key]
      : throw InvalidKeyError(key, availableKeys);

  @override
  operator []=(K key, V value) => availableKeys.contains(key)
      ? _map[key] = value
      : throw InvalidKeyError(key, availableKeys);
}

void main() {
  final availableKeys = {"cat", "dog"};
  final map = SpecialMap<String, bool>(availableKeys);

  map["cat"] = true;
  map["dog"] = true;
  map["anything else"] = false; //will throw InvalidKeyError at runtime
}
```

Although you can simply constrain through type if you want. Something like this.

```dart
enum Keys {cat, dog}

void main(){
  final Map<Keys, bool> map = {};
  map[Keys.cat] = true;
  map[Keys.dog] = true;
  map["any other type"] = false; //complie time error
}
```

Comment: mark the ansert as correct solution, please if it is what you were looking for.